# Is Genesis 28:20-22 intended as a description of Jacob's conversion/"becoming a true Jew"?

Tags: genesis-bereishith

Is Genesis 28:20-22 intended as a description of Jacob's conversion/"becoming a true Jew"? If not, what is being described?

> [Gen 28:20-22 NASB95] [20] Then Jacob made a vow, saying, "If God will be with me and will keep me on this journey that I take, and will give me food to eat and garments to wear, [21] and I return to my father's house in safety, **then the LORD will be my God. [22] "This stone, which I have set up as a pillar, will be God's house, and of all that You give me I will surely give a tenth to You."**

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "Jacob's conversion" and "becoming a true Jew".

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is as precise as I can be without influencing the answer. I'm posing the question because it seems to suggest that Jacob was up to this point not a worshipper of ha shem. It seems jarringly out of place or at least anachronistic. But I am here hoping to learn.

Comment: You assumption is off the mark. Jacob was following in the tradition of his father and grandfather. They both worshipped G-d. The inheritance that was originally transmitted to Adam HaRishon and intended for all his descendants, was restricted to Abraham, and his son from Sarah his wife. That inheritance was in turn bequeathed to Isaac's son from Rebecca. Jacob's fraternal twin sold and relinquished his claim (much like Cain did) to that inheritance, but here Jacob actively takes possession as sole inheritor.